# Customizing MulipleChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

I want to write a custom Form that will retrieve column names from a dataframe and use these columns as choices in a MultipleChoiceField. The dataframe comes from a stored file from a Model.

The code produces an error:

```
project = Project.objects.filter(id=kwargs('pk')).first()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Here is my code:

```
class PredictionCreateModelForm(forms.Form):

global COLUMNS
name = forms.CharField()
model_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PREDICTION_TYPE, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
columns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices=COLUMNS, 
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PredictionCreateModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    project = Project.objects.filter(id=kwargs('pk')).first()

    df = pd.read_csv(project.base_file)

    global COLUMNS 
    COLUMNS = df.columns 

class Meta:
    model = PredictionModel
    fields = ['name', 'model_type', 'columns']
```

Answer (score 0):

The **project** variable in your code tells if there's any object associated with that 'pk' or not. So it is not a list or dictionary. Maybe you want to try...

```
qs = Project.objects.filter(id=kwargs('pk')).exists() # True or False.
if qs:
    project = Project.objects.get(id=kwargs('pk')) # returns the object
else:
    # show error not found message
```

Comment: I edited the __init__() method with:

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        object_pk = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
        print(object_pk)
        project = Project.objects.filter(id=object_pk)

        df = pd.read_csv(project.base_file)
        columns = df.columns
        
        self.fields['choices'] = columns

        super(PredictionCreateModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` . It turned out that kwargs is empty.

Comment: Did you pass 'pk' when you called the form from your view?